# Always expand tax summary in checkout page - magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using a specific tax declaration for my magento store but on the checkout page the tax summary always starts collapsed.

Is it possible to set expanded as a default? I tried in tax.phtml but didn't get the right trick so far.

It looks like the following on my page:

default:

[image: image1]

after expand:

[image: image2]

Comment: Related: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup/issues/290

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your tax.phtml looks like mine, find the below in tax.phtml:

`<tr class="summary-details-<?php echo $taxIter; ?> summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>" style="display:none;">`

And get rid of `style="display:none;"`. I haven't fully tested it but removing display:none will show both lines of tax and should not harm your ability to also close the tax summary, either.

Comment: also class class="summary-total"  should be changed to class="summary-total show-details" to change the button to a "-" sign